# Python: Adding unpacked values (strings) of a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Is there a single line command to add two strings contained in a tuple to two existing strings in a program?

This is essentially what I want to do but in a shorter way,

```
t=("hi","hello")
x="test"
y="python"
x+=t[0]
y+=t[1]
```

I was thinking maybe there is a code like this that actually works,

```
x+,y+=t
```

[Using python's in place addition with unpacked tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588232/using-pythons-in-place-addition-with-unpacked-tuples) - I really liked the complex number solution given in this similar question, but I cannot use it since my values are strings. Or is there a way I can manipulate my data (without going into too many lines of code) so that this method can be used?

Comment: strings are immuteable - the old one gets replaced with newly created ones. what you got above is fine - using imports and other "magic" to make it fancier is deterimental to easy understanding what the code does:  **"Simple is better than complex."** - see [Zen of Python (pep-0020)/](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @PatrickArtner i know :( but i only want to make it compact, no one will be reading the code but me. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588438/13300960) answer from the question you linked, you can do this:

```
from operator import add

t = ("hi", "hello")
x = "test"
y = "python"

x, y = map(add, (x, y), t)
```

Honestly, it is rather hard to read and I would advise against using it. As far as default Python syntax goes, I doubt there is anything you could use.

Comment: I agree but thanks! Compactness is the only thing i need :)

Answer (score 1):

A single line of code doing what you expect is given below,

**Code:**

```
x, y = ["".join(i) for i in zip([x,y], t)]
```

Here [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) makes an iterator which aggregates the elements from each of the sequences passed to it. In this case it would be `[(x, t[0]), (y, t[1])]`. [.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) concatenates the elements of the list passed to it with a *separator* (`""` in this case).

Comment: `list([x,y])`? why?

Comment: `list([x, y])` is just overhead, you can use only `[x, y]`, or a tuple `(x, y)`.

Comment: @LukaMesaric Yeah I just noticed that. Thanks for the tip. Edited my answer.

Comment: @satilog No problem, also I believe OP wants `"".join` instead of `" ".join`

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I don't really understand what you've done here though. Are join and zip are part of a special module or something?

Comment: @Hiya I added some explanation and links for better understanding of the answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @satilog Thank you so much! It's all very clear now :)